# Wrong astarNode.x and astarNode.y using Phaser + AStar Plugin

Tags: a-star, phaser-framework

I was having a little trouble trying to use AStar + Phaser. I debugged it a bit and discovered a little bug. The X and Y of the astarNode property are wrong. I'm still trying to fix it, but you guys maybe help me to find the problem faster.

**Code**:

```
preload: function() {

    this.game.load.tilemap('map', 'assets/tilemap.json', null, Phaser.Tilemap.TILED_JSON);
    this.game.load.image('RPGPackSheet', 'assets/sprites/RPGPackSheet.png');
},

create: function() {

    this.map = this.game.add.tilemap('map');
    this.map.addTilesetImage('RPGPackSheet');

    this.layer = this.map.createLayer('LayerName');

    this.astar = this.game.plugins.add(Phaser.Plugin.AStar);
    this.astar.setAStarMap(this.map, 'LayerName', 'RPGPackSheet');

    console.log(this.map.layers[0].data[4][6].properties.astarNode);
},
```

[**tilemap.json**](http://pastebin.com/bQJBxMm7)

The output on the console should be:

```
f: 0,
g: 0,
h: 0,
walkable: false,
x: 4, // equals to the second index of layers[0].data
y: 6  // equals to the first index of layers[0].data
```

But is giving me:

```
f: 0,
g: 0,
h: 0,
walkable: false,
x: 24,
y: 13
```

**UPDATE:** I found out something more. My tilemap.json uses only 2 tiles (42 and 52). So when the setAStarMap() is called, he updates the X and Y of every astarNode with the current x and y that it is on the for loop (to understand better check updateMap() of AStarPlugin). In the end, every astarNode that uses 42 will have x set to 24 and y set to 13 (which is the coordinates of the last astarNode using tile 42), and every astarNode that uses 52 will have x set to 13 and y set to 12 (again, coordinates of the last astarNode using tile 52). I just can't figure out why this is happening...

Answer (score 0):

From what I know, world size in tiles of your map is supposed to be in a square size, so from what I see your world size in tiles is 25x14. So you can add a blank tiles to fill up your world map in order to get it to size 25x25